# how to get dynamic id by using selenium and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to take all id from this page by using JavaScript.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {Build, By, Key, until} = webdriver;

(async function getDiv () {
    let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    
    try {
           await driver.get('https://www.scoresandodds.com/nba');
           await driver.sleep(1000);

           var ids = driver.getElementsByName('id')
           console.log("----");
           //for (let elm of (await div)) {
           //     console.log(`${elm}`); }
           console.log(`${ids}`);



     }
     catch(error) {
                console.error(error);
     }
     finally {
                if (driver) {
                      await driver.quit();
                }
     }
 })();
```

its error, could you teach me why I canot get them?
Thank you.

Comment: Its `findElements...` not  `getElements...` and you have to await the result

Comment: That would find elements that look like <div name="id"/>

Answer (score 0):

I got this.

```
let webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
let chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
let By = webdriver.By;
let map = webdriver.promise.map;

(async () => {
    var driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
        .setChromeService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(
            "C:chromedriver.exe")
        )
        .build();    
    await driver.get("https://www.scoresandodds.com/nba");
    var elements = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='event-card']"));
    var vals = await map(elements, element => element.getAttribute('id')).then();
    vals.forEach(val => console.log(val));

    await driver.quit();
})();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).